# how to monitor file downloads within IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, logging

This is going to be a simple answer, I'm sure, but at the moment I am not sure what I need to do to get the answer.

I have been asked to provide some data on the total unique amount of downloads a particular PDF file on our webserver is getting.

I have IIS logging switched on so I presume the information about the file being downloaded will be in here, but I am not sure how I go about getting data from these files.

Anyone have any good suggestions on how I can go about getting this info ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go get the [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) utility from Microsoft.

Then use something like

```
LOGPARSER "SELECT cs-uri-stem, count(*) from c:\weblogs\w3svc1\*.log where cs-uri-stem LIKE '%/yourfile.pdf'"
```

For a real simple set of output, like:

```
/yourfolder/yourfile.pdf     6
```

Also, you'll need to work out what unique means, and then adjust the totals for that. For example, a 304 probably reflects a non-unique download, so you'd potentially:

```
LOGPARSER -i:w3c "SELECT DISTINCT cs-uri-stem, sc-status, count(*) from c:\weblogs\w3svc1\*.log where cs-uri-stem LIKE '%/yourfile.pdf' GROUP BY cs-uri-stem, sc-status"
```

**Edit:**
Web logs are (usually) just text files, one line per entry. So you don't even need to use LogParser just to get a count:

```
FIND "yourfile.pdf" ex_111207.log > justPDF.txt
```

Then open JustPDF in Excel, or get a line count in any other way.

Plus, lots of examples around.
[Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html), [here](http://logparserplus.com/Examples) and [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/forensic-log-parsing-microsofts-logparser).